# What the role of this word (available)

Tags: complex-sentences

I have a sentence.
I looked up the word "**available**" . It is ADJ.
So this sentence below have structure :
 *be* + `adj` + `N` + `adj` (*isn't sufficient detail available*)

> "There isn't sufficient detail available for all sectors to make a  fair comparison"

I'm so confused about the word "available" position. What the role of this word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Available' is part of an adjectival clause 'that is available for all sectors'. The 'that is' is unnecessary and is omitted.

'Available' could be put in a different position e.g. 'There isn't sufficient available data, for all sectors, .....'. But it is quite normal for such a clause to be placed after the noun which it qualifies.

Please note a couple of errors in the sentence. It should start with a capital letter and the apostrophe in 'isn't' goes between the n and the t, indicating a missing letter.

Answer (score 3):

In this type of sentence, where you have one adjective in front of the noun and another after the noun, the latter is used **predicatively**, which means it is connected both to the subject (like an adjective) and to the verb (like an adverb). It is similar to sentences with subject complements, such as *enough details were available*. The word *available* is also a predicative adjective in that sentence. Note that *there* is only inserted if the subject comes after the (finite) verb. Of course you could analyse it differently, as with all terms and constructions...

Comment: This explanation would be correct if the sentence were "there isn't enough detail available for me to make a fair comparison." But it's not the sectors that are making the comparison.

Comment: @PeterShor: Umm how does that change the syntax with respect to *available*? I don't see any difference if you cut off everything after *available*.

Comment: I was parsing "detail available for all sectors" as a noun phrase. So the sentence reduces to "there isn't sufficient detail to make a fair comparison". And I thought that with your parsing, if would have to be the sectors that made the comparison. But upon reconsideration, I think I'm incorrect.